# Compare date and see if password is expired(1 year) JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, date, prepared-statement

I will get the date from mySQL in the format of YEAR-MONTH-DAY ex(2013-02-01). 
How would i be able to retrieve the Date using ResultSet
and then compare it with todays date to see if its a year old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ResultSet has [getDate() methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28int%29) that will return a Date object. After that, here's a short way to compare them, if you don't care too much about precision or leap years or such:

```
Date fromDatabase = ...;
Date now = new Date();
long daysBetween = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(now.getTime() - fromDatabase.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
if (daysBetween > 365) { ... }
```

If you mean that the date is stored as a string value instead of as a date in the database, you can parse it like `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2013-02-01")`.

When dealing with dates in databases, keep time zones in mind. It can get tricky keeping things straight.